# View comments in nested node (Firebase)

Tags: json, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a commenting page on my app. When the user types a comment and taps on the reply button their comment is saved to the firebase database. See firebase structure below. The problem i have is that when i try to view the comments, the table view is blank and none of the comments are shown even when the comments are correctly saved in firebase.

I don't know if my observeComments() function is incomplete and so not able to load the comments correctly?

[image: Firebase database]

```
var comments = [Comments]()   

func obeserveComments() {

    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    
    var tempComments = [Comments]()
    
    postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children{
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
               let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
               let comments = dict["comments"] as? [String:Any],
                let degree = comments["reply degree"] as? String,
                let name = comments["reply name"]as? String,
                let text = comments["reply text"]as? String,
                let university = comments["reply university"]as? String,
                let photoURL = comments["reply url"]as? String,
                let url = URL(string: photoURL),
                let timestamp = comments["timestamp"] as? Double {
               
                let comment = Comments(id: childSnapshot.key, fullname: name, commentText: text, university: university, degree: degree, photoURL: photoURL, url: url, timestamp: timestamp)
                
                tempComments.append(comment)
                
            }
        }
        
        self.comments = tempComments
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    })
}

  @IBAction func ReplyTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // fetch the current user data from firebase
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let database = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // get data from firestore
    let docRef = database.collection("users").document(uid!)
    
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        guard let document = snapshot else {
            print("Error getting documents: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            let fullname = document.get("fullname") as? String
            let degree = document.get("degree") as? String
            let university = document.get("university") as? String
            let photoURL = document.get("photourl") as? String
    
        let commentReference = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    
        let commentObject = ["reply text": self.ReplyComment.text!,"reply name":fullname! ,"reply degree": degree!, "reply university": university!,"reply url": photoURL!, "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]] as [String : Any]
        
            //get the key for the exact post that comment is added
            let key =  self.keyFound
        
            // post comment and save it to database
            commentReference.child(key).child("comments").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(commentObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
                        if error == nil{
                            // clear the text field
                            self.ReplyComment.text = ""
                        } else {
                            // handle the error
                        }
    })
}
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentsTableViewCell
    cell.set(comments: comments[indexPath.row])
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell

}
```